# How to query the last 5 nodes of multiple content types?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I want to query last 5 nodes of multiple content types, say, `typeA`, `typeB`, `typeC`, `typeD`.

It was originally only one content type, and I did it using [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708):

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'typeA')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 5);

$result = $query->execute();
```

But now I need to include 3 other content types to the list.

Is there any way to expend this query to include the last 5 nodes of the other 3 content types as well. So that the result will have 5 last nodes from all 4 content types, altogether 20 nodes.

Or should I do it with 4 individual queries?

Comment: Probably easiest to do it with 4 individual queries.

Comment: Yeah I guess probably we have to run the same query 4 times (running query inside foreach loop, as only the content type is going to rest and rest everything is as it is) in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Yeah you'll need 4 different queries here, whether you roll them all into one with sub-queries or not. Definitely can't do it with EFQ (unless you alter the query), it wouldn't be able to express the necessary grouping

Comment: I guess you can give a try to `union` once if you want to do it with the single query.

Comment: Thanks, for your comments. Then, I'll do it with 4 individual queries. @Clive, should I keep this question or delete it? Seemingly there is no way other than what I already proposed in my question.

Comment: Nah leave it open...you never know, someone might come up with an interesting way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you need is alter the second line of your EntityFieldQuery to this:

```
->entityCondition('bundle', array('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD'), 'IN')
```

Haven't tested this particular though, but you can query multiple content types this way.

Cheers

EDIT: Maybe this can help you more: https://www.drupal.org/node/2048345

Comment: No, I want to get exactly 5 nodes from each type. Your suggestion would return 5 nodes of any given types,

Comment: Maybe this can help you then! https://www.drupal.org/node/2048345

Comment: That seems interesting. I didn't think about UNION. I'll give it a try as soon as I get the time for it. Thanks. Please edit your answer and add this link with a short description. After I try it, I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: Hey Adrian,
I really don't have the time to add short description because this is not my case and I haven't tried that. I bounced in this question for querying multiple content types only. Not exactly your case. But I will add the link to my answer as proposed by you! Again, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following codes:

```
$types= array('type1','type2','type3');

foreach ($types as $type) {
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'typeA')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 5);
  $temp = $query->execute();

  if (isset($temp['node'])) {
    $result[$type]['nids'] = array_keys($temp['node']); 
    $result[$type]['nodes'] = node_load_multiple($result[$type]['nids']);
  } 
}

/// then you can load them by
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as other have suggested using UNION is going to be the easiest way to do it with one query:

```
$nids = db_query("(SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'typeA' ORDER BY changed LIMIT 0, 5)
UNION
(SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'typeB' ORDER BY changed LIMIT 0, 5)
UNION
(SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'typeC' ORDER BY changed LIMIT 0, 5)
UNION
(SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = 'typeD' ORDER BY changed LIMIT 0, 5)")->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

I was playing with a way to do it using [numbered rows](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) but it doesn't get the latest nodes so I gave up, but here is the sql in case your interested in fixing it:

```
SELECT nid, title, type, changed
FROM (
    SELECT nid, title, type, changed,
    @num := if(@group = type, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
    @group := type as dummy
    FROM   node
    WHERE type IN ('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD')
    ORDER BY type, title
) AS x
WHERE  row_number <= 5
ORDER BY type
```

Also see this very relevant SO question [MySQL:How to get n latest rows of a distinct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950628/mysql-how-to-get-n-latest-rows-of-a-distinct-type)

Answer (score -1):

the best way you can do it is to user db_select();
I would do something like this:

Set the array with the content type machine names.

```
$arrayofnodetypes = array('page','post','poll');
```

here you select the table

```
$query = db_select('node','n'); 
$query->fields('n',array('nid','title','status','type')); // this are the fields your want to fetch
$query->condition('n.status','1','='); // node is published
$query->condition('n.type',$arrayofnodetypes,'IN'); // this is where you call the content types.
$query->orderBy('created','DESC');
$query->range(0,20);

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Then you have 2 options.

**the first:**
if you want to fetch all fields in the node, you need to manualy join the fields in the $query see the following resource if you want to learn more: https://www.drupal.org/node/1848348

**the second:**
the $results variable will have the results of the query.

I would then foreach each result of the array.

like the folowing;

```
$nodes = array();
foreach($results as $item) {
  $nodes []= node_load($item->nid);
}
```

then the $nodes array will contain the results you need.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, however this way I won't get 5 nodes from each content type, but 20 nodes, which can also be from the same type.. I need explicitly 5 from each content type.

Comment: that's easy create 5 queries and mix the results in an array.

Comment: That was already what I proposed in my question. I've asked if there were any other way to do it using only one query. Seemingly there isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use node_load_multiple.

`$types = array('content_type_1', 'content_type_2', 'etc');
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('type', $type, 'IN');`

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

$nids = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $nids[] = $row->nid;
}

$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

Comment: This is not the result I wanted to reach. I wanted to get **exactly** 5 nodes from each content type. Your solution doesn't provide that.